# Orchard cms adding data-mediapicker-uploadpath to a custom type

Tags: tinymce, orchardcms

I have created a custom type in orchard cms, that has a two column lay out

It has 2 header text fileds and 2 content HTML flavour fileds

Heres the migration :

```
public class MigrationTwoColumnPageType : DataMigrationImpl
{
    public int Create()
    {
        // Define the project type 
        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("TwoColumnPage", cfg => cfg
            .WithSetting("Stereotype", "Content")
            .CommomPart()
            .AutoroutePart()
            .WithPart("TitlePart")
            .WithPart("MenuPart")
            .WithPart("TagsPart")
            .WithPart("PublishLaterPart")
            .WithPart("TwoColumnPage")
            .Creatable()
            .Draftable());

        return 1;

    }

    public int UpdateFrom1()
    {
        // Define project part - having a part with the same name will create fields in the project type
        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("TwoColumnPage", builder => builder
           .TextField("Column1Title", Flavour.Large)
           .TextField("Column1Text", Flavour.Html)
           .TextField("Column2Title", Flavour.Large)
           .TextField("Column2Text", Flavour.Html)
           .Attachable());

        return 2;
    }   
}
```

NOTE: TextField is a custom extension method to make things less verbose

When I try and use the media picker to up load an image into one of these content fields I get a folder not found error, - I have traced this back to the media path on the Request querystring not being set

```
// media directory to save uploaded files into
    var mediaPath = Request["uploadpath"];
```

in ../../Orchard.MediaPicker/Views/admin/Tab_Url.cshtml

Is there some way to set this using filed settings ?

Seems to work fine for any pages I create, but custom types .... how do I set this value ?

**UPDATE**

Heres the xml meta data for a page...

```
<!--Exported from Orchard-->
<Orchard>
  <Recipe>
    <Name>Generated by Orchard.ImportExport</Name>
    <Author>admin</Author>
  </Recipe>
  <Metadata>
    <Types>
      <Page ContentTypeSettings.Creatable="True" ContentTypeSettings.Draftable="True" TypeIndexing.Included="true" DisplayName="Page">
        <NavigationPart />
        <CommonPart DateEditorSettings.ShowDateEditor="true" />
        <PublishLaterPart />
        <TitlePart />
        <AutoroutePart AutorouteSettings.AllowCustomPattern="true" AutorouteSettings.AutomaticAdjustmentOnEdit="false" AutorouteSettings.PatternDefinitions="[{Name:'Title', Pattern: '{Content.Slug}', Description: 'my-page'}]" AutorouteSettings.DefaultPatternIndex="0" />
        <BodyPart />
        <TagsPart />
        <LocalizationPart />
      </Page>
    </Types>
    <Parts>
      <NavigationPart ContentPartSettings.Attachable="True" />
      <CommonPart ContentPartSettings.Attachable="True" />
      <PublishLaterPart ContentPartSettings.Attachable="True" />
      <TitlePart ContentPartSettings.Attachable="True" />
      <AutoroutePart ContentPartSettings.Attachable="True" />
      <BodyPart ContentPartSettings.Attachable="True" BodyPartSettings.FlavorDefault="html" />
      <TagsPart ContentPartSettings.Attachable="True" />
      <LocalizationPart />
    </Parts>
  </Metadata>
</Orchard>
```

Here's the XML meta for my custom type, using TestFiledSetting instead of BodyPartSetting

```
<!--Exported from Orchard-->
<Orchard>
  <Recipe>
    <Name>Generated by Orchard.ImportExport</Name>
    <Author>admin</Author>
  </Recipe>
  <Metadata>
    <Types>
      <TwoColumnPage Stereotype="Content" OwnerEditorSettings.ShowOwnerEditor="false" ContentTypeSettings.Creatable="True" ContentTypeSettings.Draftable="True" DisplayName="Two Column Page">
        <CommonPart />
        <AutoroutePart AutorouteSettings.PatternDefinitions="[{Name:'/Title', Pattern: '/{Content.Slug}', Description: 'my-page'}]" />
        <TitlePart />
        <MenuPart />
        <TagsPart />
        <PublishLaterPart />
        <TwoColumnPage />
      </TwoColumnPage>
    </Types>
    <Parts>
      <CommonPart ContentPartSettings.Attachable="True" />
      <AutoroutePart ContentPartSettings.Attachable="True" />
      <TitlePart ContentPartSettings.Attachable="True" />
      <MenuPart ContentPartSettings.Attachable="True" />
      <TagsPart ContentPartSettings.Attachable="True" />
      <PublishLaterPart ContentPartSettings.Attachable="True" />
      <TwoColumnPage ContentPartSettings.Attachable="True">
        <Column1Title.TextField TextFieldSettings.Required="True" TextFieldSettings.Flavor="Large" TextFieldSettings.Hint="" />
        <Column1Text.TextField TextFieldSettings.Required="True" TextFieldSettings.Flavor="Html" TextFieldSettings.Hint="" />
        <Column2Title.TextField TextFieldSettings.Required="True" TextFieldSettings.Flavor="Large" TextFieldSettings.Hint="" />
        <Column2Text.TextField TextFieldSettings.Required="True" TextFieldSettings.Flavor="Html" TextFieldSettings.Hint="" />
      </TwoColumnPage>
    </Parts>
  </Metadata>
</Orchard>
```

No mention of data-mediapicker-uploadpath in either. I'm still lost!

Comment: You should be able to find out by making an export of the metadata for the type that works, and then examining the resulting xml file.

Comment: The Body editor view model has the property: public string AddMediaPath { get; set; }    The Text field vm dosent, I'm confused as how to amend this with out changes the orchard source code.